# Magento installation error: Module "Mage_Api2" requires module "Mage_Oauth"

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request
Module "Mage_Api2" requires module "Mage_Oauth".

Trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "Mage_Ap...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Comment: If you don't need these modules, it looks like you can safely disable Mage_Oauth and Mage_Api2: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-default-modules-i-can-disable

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, I would suggest going to http://magento.stackexchange.com/ for help.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you've got an incomplete magento source for installation or somehow the module `Mage_Oauth` was disabled. Just look in the file `app/etc/modules/Mage_Oauth.xml`, it must look like this

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Oauth>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Oauth>
    </modules>
</config>
```

maybe the active flag is not `true`