# Module install, Magento store broken (unable to use even backend) with error: "ModuleX" requires module "ModuleY"

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.9

I am facing error after I installed an extension, can't acess the backend:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:68:"Module "Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus" requires module "Fooman_Common".";i:1;s:751:"#0 /home/letsmake/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "Fooman_..
#1 /home/letsmake/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 /home/letsmake/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 /home/letsmake/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 /home/letsmake/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 /home/letsmake/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/letsmake/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:39:"/errors/default/images/btn_checkout.gif";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I found similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022851/magento-installation-error-module-mage-api2-requires-module-mage-oauth), but the I checked the solution provided, and it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Fooman_Common module. It's available [here over on Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-common.html)

Developers who create a suite of modules will often split out everything that should be in a common library and institute that as a separate module. Eases module maintenance and all that.

The [github release site](https://github.com/fooman/googleanalyticsplus) for this module has more specific instructions that tell you about the need for both modules in the install.

In the case where you have no access to the backend and you cannot access Magento Connect from using the downloader link on your website (`http://www.example.com/downloader`), you will have to manually disable the failing module and manually clear the cache.

1. Temporarily disable the **Fooman GoogleAnalyticsPlus** module by opening the module control file in `app\etc\modules`. Its name should be `Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus.xml`. Then find the xml node `<active>true</active>` and change it to read `<active>false</active>`.
2. Navigate to the `var/cache/` directory and delete all the `mage--?` subdirectories

You should now have access to the backend. Install the missing module and reverse the `<active></active>` xml node back to true, clear cache and you should be able to now work with the module you installed.

Comment: but i cant acess the backed of my site , not even admin panel 

how will i install the fooman commen extension

Comment: Added information on how to disable the failed module temporarily to correct the missing module issue.

Comment: thanks  a lot , the site is working ,  ( as it was before installing the extension )

the whole issue is due to fact that my site doesn't upload extensions via magento connect key link

thanks a lot